# Getting browser address URL with javascript inside a Team Foundation Server Widget

Tags: javascript, url, browser, tfs, widget

I'm searching for a method to get the browser address URL. Normally something like
`document.location.href` or `document.URL` would be fine, but in this special case they won't work, because the code is inside a widget for a Team Foundation Server and with this methods I get the URL of the widget.

Comment: Do you mean you customize a widget on  TFS web access dashboard, and want to get the URL of the widget? Could you give us an example of your scenario?

Comment: Well I get the URL of the widget with the methods `document.location.href` or `document.URL`. I wanted the URL of the website.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var projectname;
    var collectionname;

    VSS.init({
        explicitNotifyLoaded: true,
    });

    VSS.require(["TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers", "TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient"], function (WidgetHelpers, TFS_Wit_WebApi) {
        WidgetHelpers.IncludeWidgetStyles();
        VSS.register("commit_PNG", function () {
            var projectId = VSS.getWebContext().project.id;
            projectname = VSS.getWebContext().project.name;
            collectionname = VSS.getWebContext().collection.name;

            [....]

        return {
            load: function (widgetSettings) {                        
                return getQueryInfo(widgetSettings);
            }
        }
        });
        VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
    });
</script>
```

With this u are able to get the project- and collectionname. With these too u can build easily the URL of the website.